# read the contents of a directory using shell script

Tags: shell, directory-listing

I'm trying to get the contents of a directory using shell script.

My script is:

```
for entry in `ls`; do
    echo $entry
done
```

However, my current directory contains many files with whitespaces in their names. In that case, this script fails.

What is the correct way to loop over the contents of a directory in shell scripting?

PS: I use bash.

Comment: very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for entry in *
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: Maybe you should use 'for entry in * .*'?

Comment: @Jonathan: If you need to match files starting with a `.` then you're better off twiddling the `dotglob` option.

Comment: what is the `dotglob` option?

Comment: When `dotglob` is set (via `shopt -s dotglob`) `*` will match files that start with a `.`.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer for this question. Create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

don't parse directory contents using `ls` in a for loop. you will encounter white space problems. use shell expansion instead

```
   for file in *
    do
      if [ -f "$file" ];then
       echo "$file"
      fi
    done
```

Comment: that's bash syntax. try it and see. remember the double quotes around variables. This will preserve white spaces. Just don't use `ls` in the `for loop`