# How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, directory-listing

I'm trying to get the contents of a directory using shell script.

My script is:

```
for entry in `ls $search_dir`; do
    echo $entry
done
```

where `$search_dir` is a relative path. However, `$search_dir` contains many files with whitespaces in their names. In that case, this script does not run as expected.

I know I could use `for entry in *`, but that would only work for my current directory.

I know I can change to that directory, use `for entry in *` then change back, but my particular situation prevents me from doing that.

I have two relative paths `$search_dir` and `$work_dir`, and I have to work on both simultaneously, reading them creating/deleting files in them etc.

So what do I do now?

PS: I use bash.

Answer (score 483, accepted):

```
search_dir=/the/path/to/base/dir
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: Can you explain why `for entry in "$search_dir/*"` don't work? Why we need to place `/*` outside of quotes?

Comment: @mrgloom: Because you need to let the shell glob the wildcard.

Comment: wouldn't `find` be faster?

Comment: @AlexejMagura: `find` is a separate process. Globbing happens in the shell.

Comment: The solution gives the full path. What if I just wanted to list what was in the current directory?

Comment: Just omit the path.

Comment: @mrgloom if you want to do so you can achieve that with `for entry in "${search_dir}/*"`

Comment: it doesn't work if a file is space seprated(consider each as an entry)

Comment: on MacOs, you don't need the parentheses - just write: for entry in ~/gcloud_installs/*

Comment: This does not work recursively. For a recursive solution `find` is better. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817578/1343917

Comment: This doesn't work (in bash with the default settings) if the folder is empty or if some files start with a period.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the `| grep *.txt` from the answer below to this snippet?

Comment: @Georodin Just use `"$search_dir"/*.txt` if that's what you want.

Comment: @Anish B: Stop vandalizing the original post. The answer was right as it is written

Comment: @AnishB.: No the answer _as_ it was written should work fine for a directory name assigned to `search_dir` variable

Comment: @AnishB.: If you have a problem using the attempt, then something is not right at your end. Suggest asking a new question to resolve it, instead of modifying a highly rated answer incorrectly (Also check if your `*` is outside of double quotes)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the quoting of the `search_dir` variable. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/5291015), i.e. to protect against directory names containing spaces

Comment: @Inian I got the issue. Yes, you are right.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @MartinJambon, the "${search_dir}/*" doesn't seem to work at all for RedHat 7.9. If search_dir is empty (for any variation) or if using the latter variation, I confusingly get the contents of the current directory (assuming search_dir is not the current dir).

Comment: @GG2 You may want to initially check that the variable is set correctly before proceeding: `if test -z "$search_dir"; then echo "No search directory provided"; exit 1; fi`

Comment: @NickBull I can't remember exactly how I was trying this originally. If I revisit this now, I don't get exactly the same results. If I let an empty string past, it lists contents of root. For an empty dir or containing only files starting with ".", it just echoes the evaluated value of "${search_dir}/*", e.g. empty_dir/*. It only lists the current directory if search_dir="." We'll chalk it up to something I did wrong.

Comment: [Here are some other approaches I just added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345102/4561887) with `find` and `ls` where I capture the output into some bash arrays with `mapfile` and then customize and print the contents of the arrays.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the directory contains several files and their name contain spaces and I save the output of the command in a variable.

Answer (score 75):

This is a way to do it where the syntax is simpler for me to understand:

```
yourfilenames=`ls ./*.txt`
for eachfile in $yourfilenames
do
   echo $eachfile
done
```

`./` is the current working directory but could be replaced with any path
`*.txt` returns anything.txt
You can check what will be listed easily by typing the `ls` command straight into the terminal.

Basically, you create a variable `yourfilenames` containing everything the list command returns as a separate element, and then you loop through it. The loop creates a temporary variable `eachfile` that contains a single element of the variable it's looping through, in this case a filename. This isn't necessarily better than the other answers, but I find it intuitive because I'm already familiar with the `ls` command and the for loop syntax.

Comment: This works OK for a quick, informal script or one-liner, but it will break if a filename contains newlines, unlike the glob-based solutions.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad thanks for the advice! I didn't know newlines were permitted in filenames- what kind of files might have them? Like, is this something that occurs commonly?

Comment: Newlines in filenames are evil for this reason and as far as I know there's no legitimate reason to use them. I've never seen one in the wild myself. That said, it's totally possible to maliciously construct filenames with newlines in such a way as to exploit this. (For instance, imagine a directory containing files `A`, `B`, and `C`. You create files called `B\nC` and `D`, then choose to delete them. Software that doesn't handle this right could end up deleting preexisting files B and C instead even if you didn't have permission to do that.)

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains a large number of pitfalls with this approach. You should basically never use `ls` in scripts. It's silly anyway; the shell has already expanded the wildcard by the time `ls` runs.

Answer (score 39):

The other answers on here are great and answer your question, but this is the top google result for "bash get list of files in directory", (which I was looking for to save a list of files) so I thought I would post an answer to that problem:

```
ls $search_path > filename.txt
```

If you want only a certain type (e.g. any .txt files):

```
ls $search_path | grep *.txt > filename.txt
```

Note that $search_path is optional; ls > filename.txt will do the current directory.

Comment: No need to use grep to get only .txt files: `ls $search_path/*.txt > filename.txt'. But more importantly, one should not use the output of the ls command to parse file names.

Comment: @VictorZamanian, can you elaborate why we should not use the output of `ls` to parse filenames? Haven't heard of this before.

Comment: @samurai_jane There's a lot of links to provide regarding this topic, but here's one first search result: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. I even saw a question here on SO claiming the reasons for not parsing the output of ls were BS and was very elaborative about it. But the replies/answers still claimed it was a bad idea. Have a look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead

Answer (score 24):

```sh
for entry in "$search_dir"/* "$work_dir"/*
do
  if [ -f "$entry" ];then
    echo "$entry"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 21):

```
$ pwd; ls -l
/home/victoria/test
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:31  a
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:31  b
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:31  c
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:32 'c d'
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:31  d
drwxr-xr-x 2 victoria victoria 4096 Apr 23 11:32  dir_a
drwxr-xr-x 2 victoria victoria 4096 Apr 23 11:32  dir_b
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria    0 Apr 23 11:32 'e; f'

$ find . -type f
./c
./b
./a
./d
./c d
./e; f

$ find . -type f | sed 's/^\.\///g' | sort
a
b
c
c d
d
e; f

$ find . -type f | sed 's/^\.\///g' | sort > tmp

$ cat tmp
a
b
c
c d
d
e; f
```

---

**Variations**

```
$ pwd
/home/victoria

$ find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | sort
/home/victoria/new
/home/victoria/new1
/home/victoria/new2
/home/victoria/new3
/home/victoria/new3.md
/home/victoria/new.md
/home/victoria/package.json
/home/victoria/Untitled Document 1
/home/victoria/Untitled Document 2

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | sed 's/^\.\///g' | sort
new
new1
new2
new3
new3.md
new.md
package.json
Untitled Document 1
Untitled Document 2
```

**Notes:**

- `.` : current folder
- remove `-maxdepth 1` to search recursively
- `-type f` : find files, not directories (`d`)
- `-not -path '*/\.*'` : do not return `.hidden_files`
- `sed 's/^\.\///g'` : remove the prepended `./` from the result list

Answer (score 12):

```
find "${search_dir}" "${work_dir}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} echo "{}"
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but I can't seem to get the last `xargs -0 -i echo "{}"` command, care to explain me a bit? In particular what is the `-i echo "{}"` part do? Also I read from the `man` page that `-i` is deprecated now and we should use `-I` insted.

Comment: `-i` substitutes `{}` with the arg.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful, also for the slow minded like me I think that the `{}` is the string that is replaced with the matches by the `find` command.

Comment: It's what's replaced by `xargs`, not `find`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `-I`. Thanks for the heads up about the deprecation of `-i`.

Comment: why do you use `xargs`? by default, `find` prints what it finds... you could delete everything from `-print0`.

Comment: Doing that wouldn't handle file entries with spaces well.

Answer (score 5):

**Similar to Accepted answer - but lists only file names instead of full paths:**

This seems to have been answered a while ago, but I guess I want to also contribute an answer that just lists the files in the desired directory, as opposed to the full paths.

```bash
    #search_dir=/the/path/to/base/dir/
    IFS=$'\n' #for in $() splits based on IFS
    search_dir="$(pwd)"
    for entry in $(ls $search_dir)
    do
        echo $entry
    done
```

If you also wanted to **filter for a specific file** you would add a `grep -q` statement.

```bash
    #search_dir=/the/path/to/base/dir/
    IFS=$'\n' #for in $() splits based on IFS
    search_dir="$(pwd)"
    for entry in $(ls $search_dir)
    do
        if grep -q "File should contain this entire string" <<< $entry; then
        echo "$entry"
        fi
    done
```

*References:*

More information about IFS can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script).

More information about finding substrings in shell can be found [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash/).

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer will not return files prefix with a '`.`'
To do that use

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/* "$search_dir"/.[!.]* "$search_dir"/..?*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?

In addition to the [most-upvoted answer by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437466/4561887), consider the following solutions which also all work, depending on what you are trying to do. Note that you can replace `"path/to/some/dir"` with `.` in order to search *in the current directory.*

### 1. List different types of files using `find` and `ls`

References:

1. For `find`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71328095/4561887). See also [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327829/shell-script-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory/71328095#comment126098295_71328095).
2. For `ls`, see [linuxhandbook.com: How to List Only Directories in Linux](https://linuxhandbook.com/list-only-directories/)

**Tip:** for any of the `find` examples below, you can pipe the output to `sort -V` if you'd like it sorted.

Example:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -V
```

**List only *regular files* (`-type f`) 1 level deep:**

```bash
# General form
find "path/to/some/dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f

# In current directory
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

**List only *symbolic links* (`-type l`) 1 level deep:**

```bash
# General form
find "path/to/some/dir" -maxdepth 1 -type l

# In current directory
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

**List only *directories* (`-type d`) 1 level deep:**

Note that for the `find` example here, we also add `-mindepth 1` in order to exclude the current directory, `.`, which would be printed as `.` at the top of the directory list otherwise. See here: [How to exclude this / current / dot folder from find "type d"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525005/4561887)

```bash
# General form
find "path/to/some/dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d

# In current directory
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d

# OR, using `ls`:
ls -d
```

**Combine some of the above: list only *regular files* and *symbolic links* (`-type f,l`) 1 level deep:**

Use a comma (`,`) to separate arguments to `-type`:

```bash
# General form
find "path/to/some/dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f,l

# In current directory
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f,l
```

### 2. Capture the output of any command into a bash indexed array, with elements separated by the newline char (`\n`)

> However, `$search_dir` contains many files with whitespaces in their names. In that case, this script does not run as expected.

This is solved by telling bash to separate elements in the string based on the newline char `\n` instead of the space char--which is the default `IFS` (Internal Field Separator--see [The Meaning of `IFS` in Bash Scripting](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ifs-shell-variable)) variable used by bash. To do this, I recommend using the `mapfile` command.

The bash script static code analyzer tool named `shellscript` recommends using `mapfile` or `read -r` whenever you want to read in a string into a bash array, separating elements based on the newline char (`\n`). See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206.

Update: to see examples of how to do this with both `mapfile` and `read -r` see my answer here: [How to read a multi-line string into a regular bash "indexed" array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575442/4561887). *I now prefer to use `read -r` instead of `mapfile`, because `mapfile` will KEEP any empty lines as elements in the array, if any exist, which I do NOT want, whereas `read -r` [again, my preference now] will NOT keep empty lines as elements in the array.*

(Back to my original answer:)

**Here is how to convert a newline-separated string into a regular bash "indexed" array with the `mapfile` command**.

```bash
# Capture the output of `ls -1` into a regular bash "indexed" array.
# - includes both files AND directories!
mapfile -t allfilenames_array <<< "$(ls -1)"
# Capture the output of `find` into a regular bash "indexed" array
# - includes directories ONLY!
# Note: for other `-type` options, see `man find`.
mapfile -t dirnames_array \
    <<< "$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -V)"
```

Notes:

1. We use `ls -1` (that's a "dash numeral_one") in order to put each filename on its own line, thereby separating them all by the newline `\n` char.
2. If you'd like to Google it, `<<<` is called a "here string" in bash.
3. See `mapfile --help`, or `help mapfile`, for help.

**Full code example:**

From file [array_list_all_files_and_directories.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/array_list_all_files_and_directories.sh) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
echo "Output of 'ls -1'"
echo "-----------------"
ls -1
echo ""

# Capture the output of `ls -1` into a regular bash "indexed" array.
# - includes both files AND directories!
mapfile -t allfilenames_array <<< "$(ls -1)"
# Capture the output of `find` into a regular bash "indexed" array
# - includes directories ONLY!
# Note: for other `-type` options, see `man find` and see my answer here:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345102/4561887
mapfile -t dirnames_array \
    <<< "$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort -V)"

# Get the number of elements in each array
allfilenames_array_len="${#allfilenames_array[@]}"
dirnames_array_len="${#dirnames_array[@]}"

# 1. Now manually print all elements in each array

echo "All filenames (files AND dirs) (count = $allfilenames_array_len):"
for filename in "${allfilenames_array[@]}"; do
    echo "    $filename"
done
echo "Dirnames ONLY (count = $dirnames_array_len):"
for dirname in "${dirnames_array[@]}"; do
    # remove the `./` from the beginning of each dirname
    dirname="$(basename "$dirname")"
    echo "    $dirname"
done
echo ""

# OR, 2. manually print the index number followed by all elements in the array

echo "All filenames (files AND dirs) (count = $allfilenames_array_len):"
for i in "${!allfilenames_array[@]}"; do
    printf "  %3i: %s\n" "$i" "${allfilenames_array["$i"]}"
done
echo "Dirnames ONLY (count = $dirnames_array_len):"
for i in "${!dirnames_array[@]}"; do
    # remove the `./` from the beginning of each dirname
    dirname="$(basename "${dirnames_array["$i"]}")"
    printf "  %3i: %s\n" "$i" "$dirname"
done
echo ""
```

Here is the example output of the code block just above being run inside the [eRCaGuy_hello_world/python](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master/python) dir of my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world/python$ ../bash/array_list_all_files_and_directories.sh
Output of 'ls -1'
-----------------
autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
autogenerated
auto_white_balance_img.py
enum_practice.py
raw_bytes_practice.py
slots_practice
socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
textwrap_practice_1.py
yaml_import

All filenames (files AND dirs) (count = 9):
    autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
    autogenerated
    auto_white_balance_img.py
    enum_practice.py
    raw_bytes_practice.py
    slots_practice
    socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
    textwrap_practice_1.py
    yaml_import
Dirnames ONLY (count = 3):
    autogenerated
    slots_practice
    yaml_import

All filenames (files AND dirs) (count = 9):
    0: autogenerate_c_or_cpp_code.py
    1: autogenerated
    2: auto_white_balance_img.py
    3: enum_practice.py
    4: raw_bytes_practice.py
    5: slots_practice
    6: socket_talk_to_ethernet_device.py
    7: textwrap_practice_1.py
    8: yaml_import
Dirnames ONLY (count = 3):
    0: autogenerated
    1: slots_practice
    2: yaml_import
```

Answer (score 2):

### Get list of *files* in a directory in *`shell`* and in *`bash`*, 4 tips

#### Some remarks

- Seaching for **files** is not searching for **entries**, under Un*x, [*Everything is a file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), so under a *path*, you could find *sockets*, *devices*, *fifos*, and lot of other things which are not *files*.
- Correct [accepted answer from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437466/1765658) will fail if `$search_dir` is empty or if `$search_dir` doesn't exist.
- Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use *`arrays`*,
- and use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s *`globstar`* for recursivity instead of `find`.

### Posix `shell` first:

If you

```
search_dir="/the/path to/base/dir"
for entry in "$search_dir"/* ; do
```

(note the use of quote, for keeping space in path name)

From there, script execution will continue even if

- there's nothing in directory
- the directory doesn't exist (wrong path)
- things presents in directory are not ***files*** (named fifo, unix socket, audio device, hard disk, ...).

So next step **have to be**:

```
    if [ -f "$entry" ] ;then
        printf 'Now, you could quietly do something with "%s".\n' "$entry"
        # ...
    fi
done
```

#### Now `bash`.

##### `bash` *array*

I often use this:

```
entries=("$search_dir"/*)
```

But, same remark: this will produce an array containing `("/the/path to/base/dir/*")` in case of no file or wrong path.

You could clean 1st wrong field by using

```
[[ ${entries[0]} == "$search_dir/*" ]] && unset entries[0]
```

Or you could do a *quick loop over the array*, see at bottom of this answer...

Then

```
for entry in "${entries[@]}";do
    if [[ -f $entry ]] ;then  # ensuring entry is a file.
        'Now, you could quietly do something with "%s".\n' "$entry"
        # ...
    fi
done
```

With bash array, you could show the content of your array with full path, by:

```
printf ' - %s\n' "${entries[@]}"
```

And, for showing only file names:

```
printf ' - %s\n' "${entries[@]#$search_dir/}"
```

##### Recursion using *globstar*:

From `man bash`:

> - globstar
>   If set, the pattern `**` used in a *pathname expansion* context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

`globstar` is off by default:

```
shopt globstar 
globstar        off
shopt -s globstar
```

Then

```
entries=("$search_dir"/**)
printf ' - %s\n' "${entries[@]#$search_dir/}"
```

will print every entries under `$search_dir/`.

##### Searching for *files*.

Quick loop over array for dropping entries which are not *files*.

```
for i in ${!entries[@]};do
    [[ -f ${entries[i]} ]] || unset entries[i]
done
```

Then

```
printf ' - %s\n' "${entries[@]#$search_dir/}"
```

will print every **files** under `$search_dir/`.

##### Building array while searching for files

If your `$search_dir` do hold a lot of non-file entries, you'd better build array from tested entries:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/**;do
    entries+=("$entry")
done

printf ' - %s\n' "${entries[@]#$search_dir/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of listing files inside a directory (using a different tool, not as efficient as some of the other answers).

```
cd "search_dir"
for [ z in `echo *` ]; do
    echo "$z"
done
```

`echo *` Outputs all files of the current directory. The `for` loop iterates over each file name and prints to stdout.

Additionally, If looking for directories  inside the directory then place this inside the `for` loop:

```
if [ test -d $z ]; then
    echo "$z is a directory"
fi
```

`test -d` checks if the file is a directory.

Comment: `for [ z` is a syntax error. `if [ test` is silly and wrong. Not quoting `"$z"` is a quoting error.

Comment: Please explain. I successfully ran the code back when I wrote the answer. If you’re going to necropost at least be useful.

Comment: What's to explain? If you tested this back then, you were definitely not using a standard shell. I already pointed out the errors, and it should not be hard to look up what the correct syntax looks like, from some of the other answers here even. But check out this demo: https://ideone.com/ERcu2c and fork it to your heart's content.

Comment: If you think this is irrelevant because it's old, you don't understand how Stack Overflow works. This is regularly - probably daily - linked as the canonical answer for new users who post duplicates of this common question, but also gets probably 100x that traffic from Google searches.

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler answer with using mapfile!

```bash
mapfile -t file_list < <(ls "${some_path}")
```

Then you can use `file_list` list with all contents in  `some_path`!
If you want just file list, use `find` instead of `ls`

Ex)

```bash
// check count.
echo "${#file_list[@]}"

// check list.
for file_name in "${file_list[@]}"; do
  echo "$file_name"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ls $search_path ./* |grep ".txt"|
while IFS= read -r line
do 
   echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There are **eight existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **three hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.