# Unix for loop skipping one value in script, works properly in command line

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am running the following commands in command line:

```
for DATAFILE in `find dir_name -type f -mtime +10 | egrep -v -e 'archive/'`
do
    echo 'Data file name- ' "$DATAFILE"
    echo 'Base name ' 
    BASENAME=`basename "${DATAFILE}"`
    DESTFILE="${BASENAME}"_`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
    echo "Dest file - "$DESTFILE
done
```

I get the following result for this:

```
Data file name-  DIR_PATH_1/file_1.txt
Base name
Dest file - file_1.txt_20120719041239
Data file name-  DIR_PATH_2/file_2.txt
Base name
Dest file - file_2.txt_20120719041239
```

When I put the same commands in a shell script and execute, I get the following result:

```
Data file name-  DIR_PATH_1/file_1.txt
DIR_PATH_2/file_2.txt
Base name
Dest file - file_2.txt_20120719040956
```

I have checked the script for Control-M and other junk characters. Also, I don't have any extra steps in the shell script (no parameters and all).

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

**Update 1:**

I made the following change to the loop:

Earlier:

```
for DATAFILE in `find ${ROOT_DIR} -type f -mtime +$DAYS_ARCH | 
                     egrep -v -e 'archive/'`
```

Now:

```
find ${ROOT_DIR} -type f -mtime +$DAYS_ARCH |
     egrep -v -e 'archive/' | while read DATAFILE
```

It seems to be working properly now. I am still testing to confirm this.

**Update 2:**

Changing from FOR to WHILE loop has fixed the issue. But still I am not able to understand why this is happening. Anyone?

Comment: To add, the users running the shell script and from the command line are different. But I have given '777' to all files and directories.

Comment: Do both users use the same shell?

Comment: Your for loop appears to be treating the whole output of `find` as a single field. What else do you have in your script? Has the `IFS` var been modified?

Comment: What shell is being used for the script? It looks like some feature has been turned on in the script that isn't turned on at the CLI. I regularly get these issues as I use zsh as by day-to-day shell, but write most scripts in bash as it's more likely to be installed

Comment: As @Petesh says: I'd start by putting `#!/bin/sh` on top of the script. (**must** be the first line!)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I am using ksh. I am putting #!bin/ksh on top of the script.

Comment: Please see my update. Can someone tell me why it works with WHILE and not with FOR?

Comment: Maybe because you use the Korn-shell?

Comment: @wildplasser could you please explain?

Comment: Likely, because you have file names with special characters or spaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script/10752407#10752407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing `find` output in backticks will effectively join all lines.  This will break file names with embedded spaces.

for DATAFILE in `find ${ROOT_DIR} -type f -mtime +$DAYS_ARCH | 
                     egrep -v -e 'archive/'`

The `while read ...`  loop  will read exactly one pathname at a time, even if they contain white space or other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your script:

```
echo "My shell is: " $0
echo "My IFS is:" $IFS
```

and compare it with results from interactive shell.

Make sure your script is executed by script you want, by adding a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) line.

According to [man sh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sh.1.html), IFS is defined as:

> Input Field Separators.  This is normally set to ⟨space⟩,
>   ⟨tab⟩, and ⟨newline⟩.  See the White Space Splitting section
>   for more details.