# Unix find with spaces in filenames

Tags: macos, shell, find

I'm using the following shell script to loop through a text file, then delete anything that matches the filename there.

However, it does not work if the filename has spaces in it. How can this be rectified? Ideally my script will find and delete filenames with and without spaces....

Any other improvements to this most appreciated.

This is in OSX

Thanks for your ideas and suggestions in advance,

Dan

```
$ cat delete-files.sh
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

for i in `cat /opt/scripts/files-to-delete.dat` ;

do find /Volumes/folder/subfolder -iname $i -print -delete ;

done
```

And the text file:

```
$ cat files-to-delete.dat
LloydsTSB_Customer_Identification.html
Santander_Update_Process.html
asdasdasd asdasdasd.txt
```

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'; for l in $(cat)` performs pathname expansion, and `while IFS= read -r l` skips the last line if the file doesn't end with a linefeed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script/16145728#16145728).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input file is being read in assuming that whitespace is the field separator. Change it to newline like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

IFS=$'\n'

for i in `cat /opt/scripts/files-to-delete.dat` ;

do find /Volumes/folder/subfolder -iname $i -print -delete ;

done
```

Note the added IFS=$'\n' line.

Comment: +1: Of course, this now transfers the problem to file names that contain a newline, but fortunately they're a lot rarer than names with spaces in them. The semicolon after the `for` and `do` lines are superfluous (though I note they are in the question too; they're superfluous there, too!).

Comment: @btanaka thank you, this is perfect. And it makes sense as well. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are correct. I simply left the original script intact and added the IFS assignment. Probably would have been more helpful in a larger sense to re-write the script more correctly. In any case, you're right!

Answer (score 3):

`for i in $(cat filenames)` is a Bad Idea, for precisely the reasons you're running into. Lots more information can be found [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), but in short:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do stuff_with "$line"; done < "$file"
```

is **always** the right solution. (Note: This *will still fail* if any of your filenames contain newlines; in which case, it's probably easier to delete them yourself.)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear how to convert your suggestion to my script. Also I suspect you meant while IFS= read -r aline; correct?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My bad. I failed at transcribing from link #1. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lauri Ranta for pointing me to the most elegant solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

while IFS= read -r line

do find /Volumes/folder/subfolder -iname "$line" -print -delete

done < "/tmp/files-to-delete.dat"
```