# Bash prints whole file in one go! (Using for loop)

Tags: sorting, for-loop, special-characters, cat, ifs

I have a file whose data/output looks like this:

`7044 5.2 2:10 7856 4.7 0:27 10819 3.9 0:23 7176 3.3 0:25 7903 2.9 0:30 10850`

I am trying to print this file, step by step after a pause of 1 second.... but bash is printing the whole file all at once.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748703/iterate-over-lines-instead-of-words-in-a-for-loop-of-shell-script) answer
I added a line to change IFS, this command gives:

`IFS=$' ';for f in "$( cat output.txt )" ; do echo $f;sleep 1;done;`

gives

Also note, that `awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }' output.txt` works as desired but the commands in the `for` loop don't work iterate
step by step as desired.

Another example where the for loop does not work as expected:

`awk '{ print $2 }' output.txt | tail -n2 | head -n1` <---This works

`for i in "$( cat output.txt | wc -l )";do awk '{ print $2 }' output.txt | tail -n$i | head -n1; sleep 1; done` <---This does not work as expected.

Comment: check that the input data has the correct. I ran your commands under bash or ksh on Linux. They work properly.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba The commands are working alright. But the data is not being formatted Right. Even though i open the same file in `Mousepad`, it consists of Columns and rows. Also, there is the problem iteration in the `for` loop. The Whole data iterates in One Go..

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba It does not work in the loop for some reason.

Comment: Show the input file and the expected result. What is "One Go"?

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba The input file contents are already posted.. The expected result is that either the rows, or the elements must be printed in the iteration as you can see in the code above, i have ``sleep 1`` which means, that the whole file should not be printed. Usually it works when using the same type of loop for other file types. The lines are printed after a waiting period of 1 sec.

Comment: You mean flushing the buffer every 1s, not that you have a data error? If so, why not do eg.  awk '{print $2; system("sleep 1"); } ' output.txt

Comment: Cool. You would have received an answer in minutes if you had formulated the topic in accordance with the real problem. It is worth working on this at SO. Bash always caches STDOUT, take interest in stdbuf from coreutils, or don't use bash for such tasks. For "other formats" the instant flush also doesn't work, the data format doesn't matter here, you just overfilled the data buffer and bash flushed it periodicaly. Formulate a general, more comprehensive answer? Maybe someone will still need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it is important to find and understand the real problem before looking for a solution.
Your question boils down to you want to get a periodic, unbuffered shell data printout.

**Shell buffers the data sent to STDOUT**, so data loop works a bit differently than your intuition suggests, and it can be confusing. Data will be collected in the buffer until it is full or the program exits, then there will be a data flush. So if the chunks of data are larger or close to the size of the data buffer, you may get the wrong impression that you are operating "without buffering". The shell works differently interactively and when you redirect data to a file, which can be additionally confusing. Note that stderr is not cached.

For a better understanding, read this post  [stackoverflow.com/a/13933741/282728](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13933741/282728)

We know what the problem is. How to solve it?

**Solution 1.** The simplest code is always the best, we only need to sequentially process the data lines and delay sending each line to STDOUT by 1s. AWK is perfect for such tasks.

```
    awk '{print $2; system("sleep 1");}' input.txt
```

For ease of reference, I changed your file name from output.txt to input.txt

**Solution 2.** The GNU version of GAWK also allows you to use fflush () to flush the buffer. If you have gawk version 5.1 or less you can also use the "time" extension followed by the gawk sleep () function instead of creating a sub-shell and system sleep.

```
    gawk '@load "time";  { print $2; fflush(); sleep(1); }' input.txt
```

**Solution 3.** If for some reason we cannot or do not want to use AWK, you can use GNU sed like this:

```
    cut -d" " -f 2 input.txt | sed 'e sleep 1'
```

**To consider:**

**a.** If the problem were more complex and you hadn't used dd, cat and tee in your pipeline, perhaps you should be interested in stdbuf in the GNU coreutils package
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html

```
    stdbuf -oL [nohup] yourscript

    -o switches to stdout
    -L turn on line buffering
```

the optional nohup prevents the script from terminating after e.g. loss of remote connection, which can be useful if a task takes a long time.

**b.** If the data were to be periodicaly transferred to the result file, then the use of the script program could be considered:

```
    [nohup] script -q -c yourprogram -f output.txt

    -q mute script, block messages like "done" from being sent to stdout
    -c starts the program instead of the interactive shell
```

**c.** or write a small C program to flushed the buffer.
this is just a simple buffer underrun demonstration, not a complete solution!

```
    int x=0;
    while(x<10) {
        printf("%d",x);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        x++;
    }
```

See flush in stdlib (stdio.h) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush
sleep belongs to the POSIX standard, not C99, hence the need to use the unistd.h library
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sleep.html

**d.** Other programming languages ​​naturally have similar buffer flushing.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of `STDOUT buffers`. This is a welcome addition to my arsenal of the little programming knowledge!! Surely, it must help others here,as well.

Comment: @Dody-body I added a sed based solution