# getting filenames from directory in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to iterate a loop over all the file present in a directory using shell script. Further, I would like to display the contents from each file. I am passing directory as a command line argument.

I have a simple loop as follows:

```
for file in $1
do
    cat $file
done
```

If I run

```
sh script.sh test
```

where test is a directory, I get content of first file only.

Could anyone please help me in this?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2437452/3836908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of alternatives:

compact modification of SMA's code:

```
for file in $1/*
 do
      [[ -f $file ]] && cat $file
 done
```

or use find:

```
find $1 -type f -exec cat \{\} \;
```

Comment: but, I need only file name. Here, I get file name of the parent directory also. e.g. if my files are in test directory then the file name I get is "test/file.txt". How to get only "file.txt"

Comment: Actually I was looking for name=$(basename "$file"), but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
 for file in $1/*
 do
     if [[ -f $file ]] ##you could add -r to check if you have read permission for file or not
     then
         cat $file
     fi
 done
```