# (unix) How to write script to count the number of files in a directory using loop

Tags: bash, unix

How can I create a bash script to count the number of files in a directory using a loop.

The script should take a target directory and output: Number of files in ::

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of files in a directory in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez." Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0

if [ ! -d "$1" ]
  then
    printf "%s\n" " $1 is not a directory"
    exit 0
fi

directory="$1"
number="${directory##*/}"
number=${#number}

if [ $number -gt 0 ]
  then
    directory="$directory/"
fi

for line in ${directory}*
  do
    if [ -d "$line" ]
       then
         continue
       else
         counter=$(( $counter + 1))
    fi
  done
printf "%s\n" "Number of files in $directory :: $counter"
```

Comment: Suggested corrections:  `for line in $1/*` (the / was omitted and the {} are superfluous) and `if [ -d "$line" ]` (the filename should be quoted incase of embedded whitespace).

Comment: i did the corrections you suggested but i left the {directory}* you are right it's superfluos but i think it improves the redabilty. i also added a check on the existence of the slash.

Answer (score 1):

I would use (GNU) `find` and `wc`:

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.' | wc -c
```

The above `find` command prints a dot for every file in the directory and `wc -c` counts those dots. This would work well with any kind of special character (including whitespaces and newlines) in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop. The following will count the files in a directory:

```
files=($(ls $1))
echo ${#files[@]}
```

Comment: This will be inaccurate if any filenames contain whitespace.

Comment: This doesn't take into account directories either, they are counted as files