# Gradle caching doesn't work with GitLab-CI

Tags: java, caching, gradle, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use the caching mechanism but it doesn't work, I have tried different attempt but none of them seems to work for me. The listed tasks take about both about 75sec on my machine and on gitlab ci about 5-6 Minutes where the runner is downloading the dependencies again and in every pipeline.

**The question is how can I cache the downloaded deps with gitlab ci?**

```
image: dockerregistry.my-image:1.0.0
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gradle

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

before_script:
  - echo `pwd`
  - echo `$CI_PROJECT_DIR`
  - rm -f  .gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr .gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble

junit:
  stage: test
  script:
     - ./gradlew test
```

thanks

### Update

Executor: Kubernetes
Gitlab Version: 11.0.x

```
Submodule path 'my-other-application': checked out 'fxxxx1'
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache

.........

Running after script...
$ echo "End CI"
End CI
Creating cache default...
.gradle/wrapper: found 222 matching files          
.gradle/caches: found 8474 matching files
```

Comment: Caching in Gitlab CI can be a real pain ... Could you please edit your question to include: What do the logs say (typically in the beginning of each job) regarding caching? What type of executor (shell, vbox, ...) are you using?

Comment: @MaximilianC. I have updated the original post. The strange thing is that the job is extracting the cache but still it downloads the internet/intranet (nexus).

Comment: Mhhh. I have not worked with this executor type (to know it's quirks) nor gradle ... In your before script, could you add something that gives you an idea about whether the folder is properly filled: e.g. listing all files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script (obviously, this will be too much files to post them here :D)

Comment: Are you sure that before script is not deleting your cache?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using docker executor with this and is working:

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
```

With docker the cache is stored in the container, so if i run something like `docker system prune` and clear not running containers the cache is lost.

**I don't know how Kubernetes works, maybe the container get deleted at the end of execution.**

-> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1906

Comment: The link is very good, thx for that! As far I understood I have to configure the cache in k8s within the runner it self see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1906#note_65897542 with every step the cache is been thrown away.